# Modify Window length or Creating Multiple Windows dynamically in a running Spark Streaming Job

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

**Window Operations in Spark Streaming**

I have a question regarding the support for creating multiple windows (Window Operations) in a running spark stream.

Considering a use case where we have a running spark stream, and we have created window of certain length initially, now can we change the length of these windows in the running streaming job or can we create a few more window of different length in that running stream.

As per my understanding the window will be initialized in the driver code and then the operations for that window will be done on the workers.

But this seems to be a valid use case where we have to modify the window length in a running stream or there might be requirement for adding window of some different length without restarting the running stream.

I have been trying this, but have doubts updating the window length in a running stream.

Any help or suggestions are more than welcomed :)

Comment: Can you elaborate or mention examples where it is required to add/ modify windows at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood spark streaming you can't create/modify windows or streams at runtime. You'll have to restart the whole application in order to do that.
Or you'll have to dismiss windows altogether and use some stateful transformations which you can then conficure at runtime.